# Как специализировать шаблон для конкретного типа?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как специализировать шаблон для конкретного типа?
К примеру, у меня есть шаблонная функция sum, я хочу чтоб с интами она работала по особому

```
template <class T>
void sum(T a, T b) {
}
```

как мне сделать отдельную реализацию для интов?

Comment: `template <> void sum<int>(int a, int b)`, ¿в чем тут затруднение?

Comment: Кстати, для функций можно обойтись обычной перегрузкой :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, `template <> void sum<int>(int a, int b)`.

Но есть такое правило - не специализировать функции, если можно обойтись перегрузкой. Здесь - можно. Просто

```
void sum(int a, int b)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: *"есть такое правило"* - только правило ровно противоположное - не делать перегрузки, если можно обойтись шаблонами со специализациями. А то потом кто-то инстанцирует `sum<int>` и подорвется.

Comment: @user7860670 Я чаще слышал аргументы против: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7108033/2752075), [тык](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: @user7860670 Поддержу автора ответа — куда чаще слышал, что специализация для функций вообще от лукавого, как goto — мол, только перегрузки.